# USB serial enumeration with different power source

Tags: usb, serial, ftdi

I am working on an evaluation board that is powered off of a micro-b USB port. This also serves as a serial port (through an FTDI chip). There is a jumper that allows to choose to power the system from a different source than the USB, but doing so causes the USB-serial port to not be recognised on my computer anymore. What changes will I need to make in order to use a different power source and also get access to the serial port? 
Added a drawing of the schematic for a better picture of what's happening
[image: part of schematic]

Comment: Dou you see any pull-up resistor between D+ line and V+ rail of the different power source ?

Comment: You can get a better help if you provide a link and schematics for your "an evaluation board". FTDI chips are designed to be bus-powered only, and lack the proper D+ pull-up handling. There could be some circuit omissions when trying to use external (non-USB) source of power.

Comment: Nitpick: Many FTDI chips can be configured as self-powered devices.

Comment: Yeah I should have added a schematic. I added one, hope it is useful. To use external power I removed the jumper and plugged in an external power supply on the pin that goes to the LDO input.

Comment: Your 'schematic' shows D- and D+ short circuited. It also shows several unmarked pins connected to ground. If you don't care ...

Comment: It is a micro-b usb, the unmarked pins are landing pads attached to gnd i believe, so I left them unmarked. I don't understand how D- and D+ are short circuited. It is how it is marked in the schematic.

Comment: In fact, contrary to Ali's comment, the FTDI parts do support self-powered configuration and will enable / disable their internal pullup resistor.  Details of required connection so that they *monitor* and thus respond to USB VBus are in the data sheet.  It is correct to say that you may need to cross-check those requirements against a given board.

Comment: The  FTDI chip(entire board actually) is not directly powered directly off the the VDD USB, but through the ldo output ie VDD_33, so shouldn't the pullup en/dis should happen regardless. What am I missing?

Comment: After you powered your board externally, did you try to unplug/plug the USB cable into your computer? Did you try a different computer?

Comment: @ChrisStratton, use of GPIO DBUS7 as VBUS sense input is a kludge, and requires special conditions and re-configuration and limitations to be imposed. So I stand by my assertion that "FTDI chips are not designed to be self-powered", out of ignorance I would add.